# Codeigniter array value check

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have an array like these

```
$data=array(
'a'=>'value1',
'b'=>'value2',
'c'=>'value3',
'd'=>array('e'=>'value4','f'=>'value5' ),

);
```

By using CI how to get the value of 'e' and how to check 'e' is equal to any value or not.

Comment: Are you passing this array to a view file?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't related to CodeIgniter.

You can just do this: `$data['d']['e']`

And then to check if it's equal to any value do this:

```
if ($data['d']['e'] == $anyValue) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value as in the case of a two dimensional array..$data['d'] will select the array inside.Then get the value of 'e' or 'f' as `$data['d']['e']` or `$data['d']['f']`. If you want to compare try:

```
if ($data['d']['e'] == $Value) {
 //put your code here.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data['d']['e']);
die();
```

inside your code to check what value you have inside the index 'e'. Always use this technique. Very handy.

By the way, this is standard/raw `PHP` technique, not CI. You can use raw `PHP` in CI, there's nothing wrong with that.

Checking whether the value you have inside index 'e' is equal to a specific value, is a very basic thing you probably might've learned back in high school or grad school. It's by using an `if()` statement that you can compare your 'e' value with the specific value you have.

```
if($data['d']['e'] == 'somevalue')
{
    //do your work here
}
```